# difference between two cypher queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I am trying to run these two cypher queries and I am not understanding the difference between them. The purpose here is to find multiple paths between given two nodes such that the sum of transit_time in that path is in ascending order.

Q1 :

```
MATCH p =(:`ml`  { placeId: 960 })-[:ETA*0..10]->(:`ml`  { placeId: 814 })
return p, p as allshortestPaths, 
REDUCE(time=0, r in relationships(p) | time+r.transit_time) AS totalTime 
ORDER BY totalTime ASC
```

Q2 :

```
MATCH (from:`ml` { placeId: 960}), (to: `ml` {placeId: 814}) , 
paths = allShortestPaths((from)-[:ETA*]->(to)) 
WITH REDUCE(time = 0, rel in rels(paths) | time + rel.transit_time) 
AS totalTime, paths 
RETURN (totalTime) 
ORDER BY totalTime ASC
```

In this I get the best result from `Q1` Also these operations take very long time.
Any other better way to do that may be using graph algorithms? I think it is possible to do this using Dijkstra algorithm any help about how to specify cost_parameter there and how to use will be great. 
I am using py2neo and neo4j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neo4j has an [integrated tool to explain queries](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html), in fact it's not explaining but profiling.

You can also find [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/execution-plans.html) some documentation about execution plan, to explain each operation.

An example of execution plan with a complex query:
[image: Neo4j execution plan example]

[source](http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-real-world-performance/)